# Why is wc -l returning 0 in a sh step subshell in Jenkins/groovy

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, sh

I have a Jenkins script that looks like this

```
    stage ("Build and Deploy") {
      steps {
        script {
          def statusCode = sh(script:"""ssh ${env.SERVER_NAME} << EOF
cd ${env.LOCATION}
git clone -b ${env.GIT_BRANCH} ${env.GIT_URL} ${env.FOLDER}
cd ${env.FOLDER}
... some other stuff goes here but isnt relevant ..
sudo docker-compose up -d --build
if [ ! \$(sudo docker container ls -f "name=config-provider-*" | wc -l ) -eq 4 ]
then
exit 1
fi
""", returnStatus:true).toString().trim()
          if (statusCode == "1") {
            error("At least one container failed to start")
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

What I want is to exit with error code 1 in the script if the number of running containers is not equal to 3 (wc -l == 4 including the header), but the if statement is evaluating true and exiting with error code 1 even though i know that the containers are successfully running.

I have tried

```
          echo sh(script: """ssh ${env.SERVER_NAME} << EOF
echo \$(sudo docker container ls -f "name=config-provider-*" | wc -l)
""", returnStdout:true).toString()
```

and

```
          echo sh(script: """ssh ${env.SERVER_NAME} << EOF
echo \$(sudo docker container ls -f "name=config-provider-*")
""", returnStdout:true).toString()
```

The latter outputted 4 lines within jenkins showing all of the running containers, as expected, but the former which includes "| wc -l" returned and printed out 0 in jenkins.

I have reproduced the steps of this script line by line manually from start to finish and it works as intended when not run from within jenkins.

Additionally, manually running the command:

```sh
[ ! $(sudo docker container ls -f "name=config-provider-*" | wc -l ) -eq 4 ] && echo failed
```

echoes nothing, and the following command returns an output of 4, which is expected.

```sh
echo $(sudo docker container ls -f "name=config-provider-*" | wc -l )
```

Comment: Instead of `sh(...)` try to use `writeFile(...)` to write shell script into a file. Then try to run it from shell. Maybe it prints some information that you don't see from Jenkins because you are ignoring stdout.

Comment: Stdout is only being ignored in the actual script since I only need the status code, but I have tried echoing the result of both docker container ls, and docker container ls | wc -l with returnStdout:true separately. More info on results of those tests are in the post

Comment: could you use `writefile` or `echo` instead of `sh` and show the plain shell script you are trying to execute